# 2 одинаковых checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="rs_inp act">
                    <span class="rs_radio" data-tabname="1" data-opt="1">
                        <label>
                            <span class="radio checked">
                                <input type="radio" checked="" name="orgform" value="1">
                            </span>
                            <span class="rs_radio_text">Физ.лицо</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                    <span class="rs_radio" data-tabname="1" data-opt="2">
                        <label>
                            <span class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="orgform" value="2">
                            </span>
                            <span class="rs_radio_text">Юр.лицо</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

Есть 2 чекбокса с одинаковыми параметрами, как с помощь. jquery выполнить проверку : если первый чекбокс активен то выводим оределенный блок Div ??

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что значит "выводим определенный блок div" - в идеале хотелось бы услышать алгоритм работы (что происходит при каком действии)

Comment: у меня есть такой блок
<div class="obj">
содержимое
</div>

так вот когда активен первый чекбокс(физ.лица) вывожу содержимое obj ,
усли активен второй чекбокс (юр.лица) то я его скрываю

Comment: Не checkbox все таки, а радио ... value то у них разные, проверяйте по нему: $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', () => { if($(this).val() == 1) $('div').show(); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. `value` у радио-кнопок разные, то можно в событии `change` проверять именно `value` и, соответственно, в зависимости от него скрывать или отображать нужный вам блок:

```js
$('input[name="orgform"]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '1') {
    $('.obj').show();
  } else {
    $('.obj').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rs_inp act">
  <span class="rs_radio" data-tabname="1" data-opt="1">
    <label>
      <span class="radio checked">
        <input type="radio" checked="" name="orgform" value="1">
      </span>
  <span class="rs_radio_text">Физ.лицо</span>
  </label>
  </span>
  <span class="rs_radio" data-tabname="1" data-opt="2">
    <label>
      <span class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="orgform" value="2">
      </span>
  <span class="rs_radio_text">Юр.лицо</span>
  </label>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="obj">
  Блок для физ лиц
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо всё работает!)